# update mysql command not working -need assistance

Tags: mysql, arrays, database

the MySQL command that I am running is not updating the database. I have an image of the database in the image below showing all the various data fields (i.e. tokens).

[image]

[image]

Here is the code that is supposed to make a successful update but doesnt for some strange reason:

```
<?php

include('dbcategory.php');

$name_1 = "";
$institution_1 = "";
$instaddress_1 = "";
$monthto_1 = "";
$toyear_1 = "";
$monthto_1_1 = "";
$toyear_1_1 = "";
$graduate_1 = "";
$averages_1 = ""; 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $idz = $_POST['idz'];
    $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];

    $name_1 = $_POST['name_1'];
    /* echo $name_1; echo $full_name; */
    $institution_1 = $_POST['institution_1'];
    $instaddress_1 = $_POST['instaddress_1'];
    $monthto_1 = $_POST['monthto_1'];
    $toyear_1 = $_POST['toyear_1'];
    $monthto_1_1 = $_POST['monthto_1_1'];
    $toyear_1_1 = $_POST['toyear_1_1'];
    $graduate_1 = $_POST['graduate_1'];
    $averages_1 = $_POST['averages_1'];

    $query12 = "UPDATE education SET `full_name`=?, `name_1`=?,`institution_1`=?,`instaddress_1`=?,`monthto_1`=?,`toyear_1`=?,`monthto_1_1`=?, `toyear_1_1`=?, `graduate_1`=?, `averages_1`=? WHERE `idz`=?";

    $bb = $dbs->prepare($query12);

    $bb ->execute(array($full_name, $name_1, $institution_1, $instaddress_1, $monthto_1, $toyear_1, $monthto_1_1, $toyear_1_1, $graduate_1, $averages_1, $idz));

}

/* if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])) {
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
}    
 */

?>
```

Here's the code for the forms that do the updating:

```
    <?php
//Edit a product
//Input:
//  id: id number of the product to edit. GET.
//Path from this page to the site root.

//Title of this page.
include('dbcategory.php');
//Fetch product data.
$idz = $_GET['idz'];
//$full_name = $_GET['full_name'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM education WHERE idz ='$idz'";
$record_set = $dbs->prepare($query);
$record_set -> execute();
$row = $record_set->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$idz = $row['idz'];
$full_name = $row['full_name']; 
$name_1 = $row["name_1"];
$institution_1 = $row["institution_1"];
$instaddress_1 = $row["instaddress_1"];
$monthto_1 = $row["monthto_1"];
$toyear_1 = $row["toyear_1"];
$monthto_1_1 = $row["monthto_1_1"];
$toyear_1_1 = $row["toyear_1_1"];
$graduate_1 = $row["graduate_1"];
$averages_1 = $row["averages_1"];
/*
*session start;
* dis is a session array;
* i is a session variable;
*/
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
background-image:url('../banner.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
} 
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<html>
<body>
<br><br><br>

<H2 align="center"><u>EDIT <?php print $name_1;?> </u></H2>
<form id="myform1" action="save-edited-applications.php" method="post">
<div id="div2">

<table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:22px width="900"">
<colgroup>
<col span="1">
</colgroup>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><label for="name" size="3"> <font size="3">Name of Institution</font></label></td>
<td valign="top"><label for="institution" size="3"><font size="3">Type of Institution </font></label></td>
<td valign="top"><label for="instaddress" size="3"> <font size="3">Address</font></label></td>
<td valign="top"><label><font size="3">From</font></label></td>
<td valign="top"><label>  <font size="3">To </font> </label></td>
<td valign="top"><label><font size="3">From</font></label></td>
<td valign="top"><label>  <font size="3">To </font> </label></td>

<td valign="top"><label for="graduate" size="3">  Did You <br> Graduate?</label></td>
<td valign="top"><label for="averages">  Average <br>Grade</label></td>
<th>Save</th>   
</tr>
<td valign="top"> 
<input type="hidden" id="idz" name="idz[]">
<input type="hidden" id="full_name" name="full_name[]">

<input type="text" name="name_1[]" id="name_1" 
             value="<?php print $name_1; ?>"> </td>
<td valign="top"><select name="institution_1[]" id="institution_1" >
<option <?php if(isset($_POST['institution'])) { echo $_POST['institution']; } ?>><?php print $institution_1; ?></option>
<?php
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM institution ORDER BY institution asc";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['institution']==$_GET['id3'])
echo("<option selected value='$row1a[institution]'>$row1a[institution]</option>");
else
echo("<option value='$row1a[institution]'>$row1a[institution]</option>");
}
?>
</select></td>

<td valign='top'><input type="text" name="instaddress_1[]" id="instaddress_1" size="30"
             value="<?php print $instaddress_1; ?>"></td>

<td valign='top'><select name='monthto_1[]' id='monthto_1'> <option><?php print $monthto_1; ?></option>
<?php
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM month ORDER BY id";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['month']==$_GET['id6'])
echo("<option selected value='$row1a[month]'>$row1a[month]</option>");
else
echo("<option value='$row1a[month]'>$row1a[month]</option>");
}
?></select></td>    
<td valign='top'><select name='toyear_1[]' id='toyear_1'> <option><?php print $toyear_1; ?></option> 
<?php
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM year ORDER BY year desc";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['year']==$_GET['id7'])
echo("<option selected value='$row1a[year]'>$row1a[year]</option>");
else
echo("<option value='$row1a[year]'>$row1a[year]</option>");
}    
?></select></td>

<td valign='top'><select name='monthto_1_1[]' id='monthto_1_1'> <option><?php print $monthto_1_1; ?></option>
<?php
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM month ORDER BY id";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['month']==$_GET['id6'])
echo("<option selected value='$row1a[month]'>$row1a[month]</option>");
else
echo("<option value='$row1a[month]'>$row1a[month]</option>");
}
?></select></td>    
<td valign='top'><select name='toyear_1_1[]' id='toyear_1_1'> <option><?php print $toyear_1_1; ?></option> 
<?php
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM year ORDER BY year desc";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['year']==$_GET['id7'])
echo("<option selected value='$row1a[year]'>$row1a[year]</option>");
else
echo("<option value='$row1a[year]'>$row1a[year]</option>");
}    
?></select></td>
<?php if($graduate_1=="yes"){
echo "<td valign='top'>Yes<input type='checkbox' id='graduate_1' name='graduate_1[]' onclick='cleardata2(this)' value='$graduate_1' checked> No
<input type='checkbox' id='graduate_1' name='graduate_1[]' onclick='cleardata3(this)' value='no' disabled> </td>";
}
if($graduate_1=="no"){
echo "<td valign='top'>Yes<input type='checkbox' id='graduate_1' name='graduate_1[]' onclick='cleardata2(this)' value='yes' disabled> No
<input type='checkbox' id='graduate_1' name='graduate_1[]' onclick='cleardata3(this)' value='$graduate_1' checked> </td>";
}
?>           
<td valign='top'><input type="text" name="averages_1[]" id="averages_1" value="<?php print $averages_1; ?>"></td>

<td valign='top'><button type="Submit" name="Save">Save</button></td>
             </div>
</form>
</table>
<a href="origin.php" >BACK </a>
</body>
</html>
```

The image below shows the form to the code above:

[image]

The code runs and executes just fine without any errors in it - including the syntax or logic - but it fails to make any updates to the database tables. The tokens are in correct order. Why is not updating correctly?
Please let me know! Thanks a mill!!!

the url header for the form is: edit-education.php?idz='$idz'

i hope this helps out

Comment: enclose `array` variables into `''` like `'$full_name'` so as the rest

Comment: Are you sure `$idz` contains a valid value when you perform the update?

Comment: It's not displaying any errors because you're not checking for them. Both `prepare()` and `execute()` return false on error, so you can check and handle errors.

Comment: Shehary...it still doesnèt work...

Comment: yes Darwin, it contains a valid value when i perform the update...

Comment: how will i check and handle errors Tristan

Comment: its not working..why is this the case?

Comment: Add try catch block to see what error it reproduce when you execute the query. e.g.

try{
$db = new PDO("dbtype:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8","username","password");
$myinsecuredata=$_GET["id"];
$query=$db->prepare("Select * from table where id=?");
$query->excute(array($myinsecuredata));
}catch(PDOException  $e ){
echo "Error: ".$e;
}

Comment: I'm not a php person but, risking a downvote here, don't you need to commit the update?

Comment: i get the following error code Amit - arse error: syntax error, unexpected 'â€Œâ€‹' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\rajib\editeducation.php on line 16 - I get this error everytime I enter that code...I changed the data fields to match my database and its info...but I still keep on getting this error message on the very first line

Comment: i get the following error code Amit - parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'â€Œâ€‹' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\rajib\editeducation.php on line 16 - I get this error everytime I enter that code...I changed the data fields to match my database and its info...but I still keep on getting this error message on the very first line

Comment: what do u mean by committing the update Ben?

Comment: i made some updates...its strange that I am getting no coding or input errors of any kind...not even notices but i am getting no updates at all...like seriously...this lack of a solution is driving me nutzzzz...

Comment: is this question sooo difficult that no one can answer it? i mean i've given all the relevant details...and I get no errors...can someone just plug and paste the code in their machines and run this? i've even given the layout for the database as well...it shouldn't really take more than a few minutes max to figure out why this is not working...thnx